# How can I write this statement in PineScript?

Tags: syntax-error, pine-script, pine-script-v4

There is a problem in line 23, as I keep getting the response: 'Line 23: Syntax error: Variables of array type are not supported!' when I run the code.

```
//@version=4
// This strategy uses the RSI, MACD and Bollinger Bands to generate buy and sell signals

// RSI period
rsiPeriod = 14

// MACD parameters
fastLength = 12
slowLength = 26
macdLength = 9

// Bollinger Band parameters
length = 20
stdDev = 2

// Calculate RSI, MACD and Bollinger Bands
Arsi = rsi(close, rsiPeriod)
Amacd = macd(close, fastLength, slowLength, macdLength)
AupperBand = bb(close, length, 1)
AlowerBand = bb(close, length, -1)

// Buy signal: RSI below 30, MACD positive and crossing above 0, and close below lower Bollinger Band
bool buySignal = Arsi < 30 and Amacd > 0 and close < AlowerBand

// Sell signal: RSI above 70, MACD negative and crossing below 0, and close above upper Bollinger Band
bool sellSignal = Arsi > 70 and Amacd < 0 and close > AupperBand

// Plot buy and sell signals
plot(buySignal ? 1 : 0, "Buy", green, 4)
plot(sellSignal ? 1 : 0, "Sell", red, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

`macd` and `bb` return tuple, so you need to get their return values with `[ ]`.

> macd(source, fastlen, slowlen, siglen) → [series[float],
> series[float], series[float]]
>
> bb(series, length, mult) → [series[float], series[float],
> series[float]]

You can use `_` to ignore a return value.

```
[Amacd, _, _] = macd(close, fastLength, slowLength, macdLength)
[_, AupperBand, _] = bb(close, length, 1)
[_, _, AlowerBand] = bb(close, length, -1)
```